# I need to add the row between two rows , whenever i am adding the row it is adding at the last at footer row :

Tags: asp.net, datagridview

protected void AddNewExpressions(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool FilterNot = ((CheckBox)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("CheckBoxNot")).Checked;
bool LeftParen = ((CheckBox)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("CheckBoxLeftParen")).Checked;
string FilterField = ((DropDownList)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlField")).SelectedItem.Text;
string FilterOperatorIdStr = ((DropDownList)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlOperatorDesc")).SelectedItem.Value;
int FilterOperatorId = Int32.Parse(FilterOperatorIdStr);
string OperatorDesc = ((DropDownList)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlOperatorDesc")).SelectedItem.Text;
string FilterValue = ((ComboBox)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("comboBoxValue")).SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
bool RightParen = ((CheckBox)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("CheckBoxRightParen")).Checked;
string ConjunctionIdStr = ((DropDownList)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlConjunctionExp")).SelectedItem.Value;
int ConjunctionId = Int32.Parse(ConjunctionIdStr);
string ConjunctionExp = ((DropDownList)GridViewExpressions.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlConjunctionExp")).SelectedItem.Text;
DataType DataTypeOfFilterField = filterBuilderRepo.FindFilterDefinedFields(int.Parse(cboProductId.SelectedValue.ToString()), chkBoxHistory.Checked, int.Parse(cboSOR.SelectedValue.ToString()))
.Where(x => x.ColumnName == FilterField)
.Select(y => y.FieldDataType)
.SingleOrDefault();

```
        // format value - add '' if needed
        FilterValue = FormatValue(FilterField, OperatorDesc, FilterValue);

        // add new row in dtForExpressionsGridView
        DataRow newRow = dtForExpressionsGridView.NewRow();
        newRow["FilterExpressionId"] = Guid.NewGuid();
        newRow["FilterNot"] = FilterNot;
        newRow["LeftParen"] = LeftParen;
        newRow["FilterField"] = FilterField;
        newRow["FilterOperatorId"] = FilterOperatorId;
        newRow["OperatorDesc"] = OperatorDesc;
        newRow["FilterValue"] = FilterValue;
        newRow["RightParen"] = RightParen;
        newRow["ConjunctionId"] = ConjunctionId;
        newRow["ConjunctionExp"] = ConjunctionExp;
        int row = Convert.ToInt32(GridViewExpressions.EditIndex);
        dtForExpressionsGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

I am trying to add row between two rows or i want to add the row randomly between Two roaws which have the same data field .